# Menu icon is appearing UNDER the logo - want it aligned to the right

Tags: css, mobile

On this page:  http://diablogym.net/

When you use a mobile device like a tablet or cell phone the logo covers the menu icon button.  I want that icon to appear on the right - logo on the left.  I can't figure out how to do that.  Can anyone supply the css to fix that?

thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D
Yes, I understand what you are saying.  I will do it differently or add in the code in the answer.
`Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles on this site seem very messy...

In order to fix it I removed the float, position, width and height from '.nicdark_logo' (why is the height set to 10px?).  I also took the position: absolute; off of '.nicdark_logo img'.  This makes the logo appear above the menu.

Beyond these changes, I would suggest centering the logo and scaling it down a bit so your sticky header isn't taking up so much of the page.

Comment: I was able to analyze things again and just float the menu to the right which left the logo on the left using this custom css.
.menu-diablogym-menu-container {
    float: right;}